# How to show that the graph is outside of the osculating circle when, arclength parametrization curvature is simple.

Tags: calculus

**Problem**
Suppose we have a curve in the plane with arclength parametrization r(s) that has infinitely many continuous derivatives. Suppose that the curvature at s=0 has a local maximum. Moreover, suppose that this maximum is "simple", i.e. the first derivative of the curvature is 0, and the second derivative of the curvature is negative.
Prove that the curve locally around s=0 is located outside the osculating circle for s=0. In other words, prove that there exists ε>0 such that r((-ε,ε)) is located outside the osculating circle, except the point r(0) itself.

**My attempt** First, I show that there is a small region such that k''(s)<0 since it is smooth.
I used Taylor expansion and showed that for such region,
k(s)=k(0)+k'(0)s+1/2k''(c)s^2<k(0).
So, now I know that it has a greater radius of the osculating circle for all points.
It looks obvious that the graph is outside of the circle but I cannot express in mathematical words.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it’s obvious that the graph lies outside the circle?

Comment: It may be a bit wrong to say that it is obvious. What I meant was that intuitively it seemed right. A larger radius makes it look like it is further away from the center when I think about the shape of the graph.

Comment: @Divide1918 Maybe my intuition might be wrong.